# Update User Column in Parse with New Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to update the telephone column and name column in the User Class with new values entered by user. I am using the same code recommended by Parse. Avoided changing anything except what is needed to try it out, but it is triggering an error. This is the error I get when I click to update the telephone and name of the user.

> 2015-12-08 20:55:26.044 Mawq[39532:1084556] [Error]: No results
>   matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.10.0) Optional(Error
>   Domain=Parse Code=101 "No results matched the query."
>   UserInfo={error=No results matched the query.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=No results matched the query., code=101})

and this is the code in the function:

```
if(nameTextField.text != "" && telephoneTextField.text != "")
        {
            /*Update*/
            let query = PFQuery(className:"User")
            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {
                (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
                    print("Telephone New: " + self.telephoneTextField.text!);
                    gameScore["telephone"] = self.telephoneTextField.text!
                    gameScore["name"] = self.nameTextField.text!
                    gameScore.saveInBackground()
                }
            }
        }
```

And the parse documentation is here:
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-updating-objects

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `User` column in Parse?

Comment: I want to update the telephone column and name column in the User Class with new values entered by user.

Comment: Have you tried this method: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-signing-up ?

Comment: @lukesIvi I used that for a signup function but it's not relevant here since am updating 2 columns not creating a new record

Comment: Why are you querying when you already have the user - just retrieve `PFUser.currentUser()`, update that object and then save it

Comment: @Paulw11 That's another possible way. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be the fact that Parse uses the User className as "_User".

So try:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
```